# Load image from resource folder not working in EL / Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I trie to get working the EL tag that i can show an image from my resources folder but it dosen't seem to work.
The following example:

my xhtml

```
 <p:dock position="bottom">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{resource['icon:img/exit.png']}" url="#" />
 </p:dock>
```

And also i tried:

```
<p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{resource['img/exit.png']}" url="#" />  

<p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{resources['img/exit.png']}" url="#" />

<p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{resource['default:img/exit.png']}" url="#" /> 

<p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{resources['img:exit.png']}" url="#" />
```

All of the above didn't work.
Whats wrong?
I have set the web.inf tag as follow:

```
  <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

**EDIT**

Have solved my own problem.
I have add the folder in the META-INF and i worked. 
Very strange

Comment: I use like that `#{request.contextPath}/resources/img/exit.png`

Comment: I assume you have debugged, increased server side logging and more and found some relevant information in there

Comment: You have to register resource libraries first to access its items. You can find some information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used